# CombineLatest and cold observables

Tags: java, rx-java, observable

Given the following code:

```java
        Observable<String> obs1 = Observable.just("1", "2", "3");
        Observable<String> obs2 = Observable.just("a", "b");
        Observable.combineLatest(obs1,
                                 obs2,
                                 (s1, s2) -> s1 + ":" + s2
        ).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

I would expect it to print something like the following:

```
1:a
2:a
3:a
3:b
```

But it prints

```
3:a
3:b
```

Why is my first Observable only emitting the last item? There are no active subscriptions before combineLatest, so it should be cold. How can I make sure all items from both Observables are combined together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you have synchronous sources. When `combineLatest` subscribes to its sources, it prefetches 128 elements by default from them. This means that your first source will run to completion synchronously and the second subscription doesn't even happen until that completion. Since the first source is alone, all but the very last element gets dropped. Once the second source is subscribed, it will find the very last from the first and combine itself with it.

What were you trying to achieve? If you want pairwise combination, use `zip`. If you want all combinations of first and second, use `flatMap`:

```
obs1.flatMap(v -> obs2.map(w -> v + ":" + w)).subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Well actually my code works because my source isnt synchronous, I stumbled on this when trying to write a test for it.<br/>
What I'm trying to achieve is the following:
<ul>
* query Mongodb to get an Observable with a stream of existing id's.
* query AWS s3 to get an Observable with a stream of filenames
* for each s3 file, check if the filename exists in mongo. If not, remove the file from s3.
</ul>

Comment: @akarnokd : with your flatMap, `obs2` will subscribe only after the first value of `obs1` is emited. With `combineLatest` the subscription is sequential. Is any way to have `obs2` subscribing just after `obs1` subscription ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, akarnokd. The prefetch of 128 items is very useful insight. I have solved my problem by switching the two Observables, so

```java
Observable<String> obs1 = Observable.just("1", "2", "3", "4");
Observable<String> obs2 = Observable.just("4", "b", "1");
Observable.combineLatest(obs1,
                         obs2.toList(),
                         (s1, list) -> list.stream().anyMatch((listItem) -> s1.contains(listItem)) ? null : s1)
          .filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty)
          .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

is now working as follows:

```java
Observable<String> obs1 = Observable.just("1", "2", "3", "4");
Observable<String> obs2 = Observable.just("4", "b", "1");
Observable.combineLatest(obs2.toList(),
                         obs1,
                         (list, s1) -> list.stream().anyMatch((listItem) -> s1.contains(listItem)) ? null : s1)
          .filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty)
          .subscribe(System.out::println);
```